# Deep eager load on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization

In this thread know [how to make a eager load in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406572/different-implementation-on-ror), **but how to do this nested**?

I.e:

```
# get category, random product and random photo
@category = Category.find(params[:id], :include => random_product, :include => random_photo)
```

I don't know if I explain...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eager load nested associations by giving a hash to the :include option:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id], :include => { :random_product => :random_photo})
```